# Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, if $0 < a < b$ then $0 < a^2 < b^2$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove:

> For all real numbers a and b, if $0 < a < b$ then $0 < a^2 < b^2$

This is my first class in formal proofs, and I'm not sure where to begin. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Just use the fact that if $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, then $0 < a < b$ implies $0 < ca < cb$.

Comment: See [Axioms for total ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach): if x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 0 then xy ≥ 0. Thus, from $0 < a < b$ we get $0 < a^2<ab$ and also $0 < ab < b^2$.

Comment: You can write $b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your list of axioms regarding $\lt$.  You should have one that says something like if $c,d,e \gt 0, d \lt c,$ then $ed \lt ec$  You should also one that says $\lt$ is transitive, that if $c \lt d$ and $d \lt e$ then $c \lt e$.  You want to use these by finding something between $a^2$ and $b^2$ that you can relate to both.